# AFNetworking 401 on device, working on simulator

Tags: ios, afnetworking

So - I have identical AFNetworking code, that, when run on the simulator, returns results as expected, and gives me all the proper JSON back.

Soon as I run it on the device, I get a 401. Now, I understand this means 'unauthorized,' but how on earth does it run absolutely swimmingly on the simulator and then give me a 401 on the device?

The code is below and has only been changed to remove the address of our API which must remain private.

```
phoneNumber = phoneNumberField.text;

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:phoneNumber forKey:@"phone_number"];

NSString *UDIDstring = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

NSLog(@"UDID: %@",UDIDstring);

NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"userId\":\"%@\",\"userType\":\"%@\",\"deviceId\":\"%@\",\"deviceType\":\"%@\"}",phoneNumberField.text,@"Number",UDIDstring,@"iPhone"];
NSLog(@"json: %@",jsonRequest);

NSDictionary *stuff = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       phoneNumberField.text, @"userId",
                       @"Number", @"userType",
                       UDIDstring,@"deviceId",
                       @"iPhone",@"deviceType",
                       nil];

NSLog(@"stuff: %@",stuff);


NSError *error;

NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:stuff options:0 error:&error];

NSString *urlString = @"(hidden for privacy reasons)"

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  timeoutInterval:10];

NSString *userpass = [@"vclient:VastV1" base64EncodedString];
NSLog(@"userpass: %@",userpass);

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic: %@",userpass] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
//[request setValue:@"*/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
    securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
    op.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];


[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"JSON responseObject: %@ ",responseObject);

    [infoLabel setText:@"You have been sent an activation code to the number you used. Please enter it above."];

    [signupLabel setText:@"your code:"];

    [mainButton setTitle:@"Activate" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    firstSignup=true;

    [phoneNumberField setText:@""];

    [phoneNumberField setPlaceholder:@"Enter activation code."];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}];
[op start];
```

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? Is it a self-signed cert?

Answer (score 1):

One difference would be that you are reporting a different device ID. Maybe the API that you are using keeps track of device IDs that have been authorized. And your Mac has been authorized, but the iOS device hasn't.

You could try logging the device id on the Mac, and then change your code to use that ID as a hardcoded string, instead of using what the iPhone returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I do it all the time

`#import "AFNetworking.h"`

```
NSDictionary *params = @{ @"key1": txtBox1.text, @"key2", txtbox2.text};
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializerRequest = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
AFJSONResponseSerializer *serializerResponse = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[serializerRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]];
serializerResponse.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];

manager.requestSerializer = serializerRequest;
manager.responseSerializer = serializerResponse;

[manager.securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];

[manager POST:@"url"
   parameters:params
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        // DO WHAT YOU WANT IF SUCCESSED
      }
      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // DO WHAT YOU WANT IF FAILED
      }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an authentication scheme that depends on the time? I've seen drift on the simulator that causes it to 401.